# How to get following element of span based on text within span

Tags: html, selenium, html-lists

How to identify following element of span using the text that is within the span.
In the code below I need to identify the first span using its text to find the following element in `<li>`. I could identify the span using its class attribute, but i could not use `contains(text(), 'System stopped operation')` to identify the span tag. My idea was to identify the first span using its class and then find the following `<li>`

```html
<span class="text-danger">
      &nbsp;
      <img src="images/crit.gif" width="15" height="15" border="0" align="absbottom" alt="Critical Alarm" title="Critical Alarm">
      &nbsp;System stopped operation
    </span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        The system is not in operation.</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="text-warning">
      &nbsp;
      <img src="images/warn.gif" width="15" height="15" border="0" 
    align="absbottom" alt="Warning Alarm" title="Warning Alarm">
    &nbsp;System restarted
    </span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        System has been restarted.</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: the bullets in text formatting look funny. Please remove.

Comment: Are you trying to locate the `SPAN` or the `LI`?

Comment: @JeffC: the text in SPAN and LI are related... I need to get them both. I have many such elements in the page and the "class="text-danger' is same for all of them. The difficulty I have is how do I get the LI element based on the preceding SPAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the `<li>` element with respect to the text within the respective `<span>` tag, you can use the following *xpath* based solution:

- To identify the `<li>` with text as **The system is not in operation**:

  ```
  //span[contains(., 'System stopped operation')]//following::ul[1]/li
  ```
- To identify the `<li>` with text as **System has been restarted**:

  ```
  //span[contains(., 'System restarted')]//following::ul[1]/li
  ```

Comment: This doesn't work because the `contains()` won't find the `SPAN`.

Comment: Great... thanks @DebanjanB... I was able to find using your solution...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the question if you are looking for the `SPAN` or the `LI` under the `SPAN`, so here's both.

You can use the CSS selector below to find the `SPAN`

```
span.text-danger
```

or the CSS selector below to find the `LI` under the desired `SPAN`

```
span.text-danger + ul li
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191401/discussion-on-answer-by-jeffc-how-to-get-following-element-of-span-based-on-text).